# trying to parse JSON data results in undefined error

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js

I'm trying to load a local .json file in my NodeJS application and loop through the items, loading them in a ordered list. I've created my main js file and the model for the data, plus the main html page but I get a strange error. I receive document not defined in my data.js file:

> document.getElementById('update').appendChild(makeUl(dataObject));

Here is my main js file, app.js:

```
var express = require('express' );
var app = express();
var bodyParser  = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname+ '/client'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var Data = require('./models/data.js');

app.get('/', function(req,res){
    res.send("Please use /api/data");
});

app.get('/api/data',function(req, res){
    Data.getData(function(err, data){
        if (err){
            throw err;
        }
            res.json(data);
    });
});
app.listen(5000);
console.log('Connected');
```

and here is my data.js file where I receive the error:

```
var dataObject = require("../jsondata/reduced_dataset.json");
function makeUL(array) {
    // Create the list element:
    var list = document.createElement('ul');

    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        // Create the list item:
        var item = document.createElement('li');

        // Set its contents:
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[i]));

        // Add it to the list:
        list.appendChild(item);
    }
    // Finally, return the constructed list:
    return list;
}
document.getElementById('update').appendChild(makeUL(dataObject));
```

I don't understand why I receive this error since I've linked it in the html page:

```
<html>
<head> 
    <title>Data Parsing</title> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id = "update"> </div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src ="./models/data.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using your json as an array. Post a snippet of the json file.

Comment: the json file is huge. The problem is not in the file but the fact that the data.js file returns an undefined error towards the html.

Comment: Is that JS running server-side in Node, or client-side in the browser? Your main app.js looks like server-side code to me.

Comment: Yes, the main app.js is the server side which allows me to load the json file. The reason for that is that nodejs supports `var dataObject = require("../jsondata/reduced_dataset.json");` to be called.

Comment: So are you getting the error about `document` not defined server-side? Doesn't `var Data = require('./models/data.js');` try to run your client-side JS on the server, hence the error? What is the `Data.getData()` function that you call but don't show?

Comment: I'm just trying to read the passed on data from the local json file. I'm using the GET method to access the data loaded in **data.js**

Comment: So, again, are you getting the error about `document` not defined server-side? Why is a file of server-side JS (app.js) included in a `<script>` element? The whole structure doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117648/discussion-between-zombiechowder-and-nnnnnn).